# Issue with Angular file while building dist on Jenkins(CI/CD)

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am facing some problems while building the dist folder of the angular file.
I am able to build the dist with the help of CI/CD on AWS ec2 Linux instance successfully for the angular file, but the changes done by my team in the code are not reflecting correctly on a web server.
After changing the dist path on the server and custom service the changes reflects properly but these changes don't reflect every time. If I change the URL for ex:- FROM https://xyz.company-domain.com TO https://abcd.company-domain.com, the changes done by my team reflect successfully.
If I build a new server setup on the new AWS Ec2 Linux instance the changes reflect for the same CI/CD build.
Also, I have tried to resolve the issue by clearing caches for angular on the server and Cloudflare but the issue is still persisting.

For reference,
I am using NGINX and Cloudfare

Comment: You should tell us if you're using some webworkers because there might be some cache directly in devices due to that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.